# Setting 'ForwardTo' property on Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription through Powershell

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Since it appears that setting the 'ForwardTo' property of a Topic Subscription is not enabled through ARM templates, how do you set the 'ForwardTo' property of an existing Topic Subscription through Azure Powershell?  I have seen examples in code, using the SDK, but cannot get it working through Powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\computeruser> $subscription = Get-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription -ResourceGroup infrastructure-dev-rg -NamespaceName myServiceBus -TopicName eventFeed -SubscriptionName Event-Subscription

PS C:\Users\computerUser> $subscription.ForwardTo = 'topicToForwardTo'
The property 'ForwardTo' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the 
property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $subscription.ForwardTo = 'ana'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [server-side issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/88) that needs to be fixed by the Azure Service Bus team. Once that's done, ARM will be able to use those properties. Suggest to track the GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/88 for status update. Until then, you won't be able to achieve it with ARM and would need to resolve to the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus client.

Answer (score 0):

Add Sean Feldman's answer. The reason for the error log is that `Get-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription` could not list `property` ForwardTo.

```
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> Get-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription -ResourceGroup shuivm -NamespaceName shuitest -TopicName shuitopic -SubscriptionName shuisub|fl


Name                             : shuisub
AccessedAt                       : 11/22/2017 2:35:39 AM
AutoDeleteOnIdle                 : P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S
CountDetails                     : Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Models.MessageCountDetails
CreatedAt                        : 11/22/2017 2:35:37 AM
DefaultMessageTimeToLive         : P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S
DeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration : False
EnableBatchedOperations          : True
LockDuration                     : PT1M
MaxDeliveryCount                 : 10
MessageCount                     : 0
RequiresSession                  : False
Status                           : Active
UpdatedAt                        : 11/22/2017 2:35:39 AM
```

Currently, at this time Azure Resource Manager does not support ForwardTo, hence it isn't possible to set using Azure Power Shell and template.

But you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-namespace-topic-with-rule), it will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

It will work via the older Service Management (RDFE based) PowerShell though
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2014/12/02/how-to-create-service-bus-queues-topics-and-subscriptions-using-a-powershell-script/.

Apart from that you can use the client libraries, this is not currently possible as the `autoforward` feature is not supported by the resource manager API.